# Connect to Microsoft Projects o-data feed in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, odata, azure-data-factory

I have a Project Web App Site in SharePoint. I want to connect to the `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/_api/ProjectData` o-data feed in Azure Data Factory.

- I created an App registration with permissions to sharepoint.
  [App permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQOV.png)
- I connected the app registration with the sharepoint site on `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx`
  with these permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read"/>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read"/>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver" Right="Manage"/>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/projectserver/projects" Right="Read"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

- I created a pipeline and an o-data dataset in Azure Data Factory. When I am testing the connection I get an error message:

```
{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}.
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQsST.png)
What did I miss?